# Scrolling for more items than will fit on screen

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollview

I have a display screen that has more items than will fit.  I would like to make it scrollable
but cant figure out the XML. I have below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Auto Settings"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    //more items
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

It throws an error at the first linear layout.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's plain XML syntax error. Terminate your `ScrollView` tag with `>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageUser"
            android:layout_width="108dip"
            android:layout_height="81dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_profile" />

        // more items
    </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```